# Synchronize npm dependency package branch with a current project during CI

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, continuous-integration, package

I have a nodejs project which depends on a separate library I develop. The question what is the best practise to automatically install the library with a same branch (or master if it doesn't exist) in a current project during CI stage (or not just this stage).

In a place I was working we did it by coping the library to the current server and including this directory as a local dependency in `package.json`. But it seems like a big scratch, I wonder if there are a more ellegent or idiomatic way to achive the same result?